# While converting PHAsset to UIImage losing transparency

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage, phasset

After I pick an image from Image picker and try to convert PHAsset to UIImage image is losing transparency of the png Image. 
I tried searching everywhere but didn't find anything about it.

```
  func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
        let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        option.synchronous = true
        manager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 341.0, height: 182.0), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
            thumbnail = result!
        })
        return thumbnail
    }
```

> Image before

[image: IMAGE BEFORE]

> After selecting and setting it to image view

[image: AFTER SELECTING AND SETTING IT TO IMAGE VIEW]

Comment: Have you tried using the original image data to create an image, i.e. Call `requestImageDataForAsset` with `PHImageRequestOptions.version = . Original`. You can then create the image from `UIImage(data: data)`.

Comment: no, I ill try to hold on a second

Comment: @LukeVanIn i tried not working

Comment: Yeah, Luke, it worked  post it as answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: Great when a hunch works out :) Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the original image data by calling `requestImageDataForAsset` with `PHImageRequestOptions.version = . Original`. You can then create the image from `UIImage(data: data)`.

Example:

```
 func getThumbnail(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage? {

    var thumbnail: UIImage?

    let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()

    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()

    options.version = .Original
    options.synchronous = true

    manager.requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: options) { data, _, _, _ in

        if let data = data {
            thumbnail = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }

    return thumbnail
}
```

Comment: it returns nil somethimes as image is set from inner block, is there any solution for this issue???

Comment: It works BUT users want to see transparent and cropped (adjusted) image, how to deal with it?